# Is the given sentence grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality

> "I haven't read much of Shakespeare's works."

If one used the above sentence, would it be grammatically incorrect?

Comment: I think if you're using much, you should write : I haven't read much of Shakespeare's work. Or you can say I haven't read many of Shakespeare's novels/plays.  
I'll also wait for an answer.

Answer (score 2):

It's borderline grammatical, but certainly awkward.

We normally use "much" with uncountable quantities, which contradicts the apparently countable "works". 
As v kumar says, changing "works" to "work" will fix it.

Another apparent way of "fixing" it - changing "much" to "many - clearly changes the meaning: "I haven't read many of Shakespeare's works" refers to the number of complete plays or poems you have read.

An alternative might be "I haven't read much from Shakespeare's works". I don't think many people would say that, but grammatically it is fine, because the object is then not "much from Shakespeare's works", but just "much", with "from Shakespeare's works" being an adjunct to the whole predicate.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is correct to use the above sentence if we replace works with work as has been said in the previous answer because work is not a countable quantity..or I think sometimes people even use.."I haven't read much from Shakespeare."....